# refactoring namespace in RESTFul WCF causes error at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, asp.net-mvc-4

I create a "WCF Service Application" project.

I make the interface, then class, a [DataMember] decorated object, and Global.asax.cs Global class in the same namespace, `parentns.mynamespage`.

I run this in VStudio IIS Express and everything is great.

.

Then I realize I want to refactor the namespace to `parentns.subnamespace`.
That is the only change alone in Imyclass.cs (the object also exists in this file), myClass.cs, and Global.asax.cs recompile and F5-run again in VStudio Imyclass

Now I get:

> "the remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error"

Nothing is reported of interest in the Output window except a very generic

> "Exception thrown: 'System.Net.WebException' in System.dll"

If I Ctrl-Z everything and rerun everything works again.

What else am I needing to refactor?

How do you troubleshoot this?

Thanks for you help

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. Immediately after posting this question I had the thought to search-and-replace.

I found a reference in the primary global file 'Global.asax' pointing to the old namespace.  Updated that and everything works fine.

Thanks.